# Nestjs httpModule url params as object

Tags: typescript, nestjs, url-parameters, httpmodule

Is there a way of passing url params to httpService in nestjs? I'm trying to write this URL in a more accessible way and don't want to use Axios since nest has an `HTTPModule`.

Here is what I have currently and it works fine but looks bad:

```
const response = await this.httpService
      .get(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}/repos?per_page=5&sort=created:asc&client_id=${process.env.GITHUB_ID}&client_secret=${process.env.GITHUB_SECRET}`,)
      .toPromise();
```

I've found this syntax for angular but it's not working:

```
const response = await this.httpService.get(
      `https://api.github.com/users/${username}/repos`,
      params: {
        per_page: 5,
        sort: created:asc,
        client_id: process.env.GITHUB_ID,
        client_secret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET
      }).toPromise();
```

There has to be a way to make it look better.

Comment: That should be working with the `HttpService` for NestJS. What error(s) do you get?

Comment: In console: error TS1005: ',' expected. Highlighted in vs code: Cannot find name 'params'.ts(2304)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the opening and closing brace for the options object.

```js
const response = await this.httpService.get(
  `https://api.github.com/users/${username}/repos`,
  {
    params: {
      per_page: 5,
      sort: created:asc,
      client_id: process.env.GITHUB_ID,
      client_secret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET
    }
  }
).toPromise();
```

Without that, you're basically saying use the variable `params` of type `{ per_page: 5, sort: created:asc, client_id: process.env.GITHUB_ID, client_secret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET }` (I'd expect Typescript to complain about using values as types here as well)

Comment: Now that .toPromise is deprecated how would you rewrite this solution?

Comment: `await lastValueFrom(this.httpService.get(url, options))`

Comment: Thanks for responding....is there an advantage doing it this way versus using a .post?